# Python - How to search in a user's timeline?

Tags: python, django, twitter

I am doing a python Django project. Here I need to search tag and return the tweets only from my desired users.

To get user's tweet, I can use https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=10

To get search tag, I can use http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%40twitterapi

BUT, I want to use both in a same API. Please help me.

Note : I got idea and tried using search API first and filtering via username (from_user), but this is not doing good. While searching we are getting top 50 tweets and filtering with desired username give results VERY RARELY.

So, I should get the timeline and search. In python, is there any way to search a STRING in a python dictionary ?

Thanks in advance,
vsnu.

Comment: Seems like the twitter and django stuff doesn't matter here - *how do I search for a string in a python dictionary?* is the only question I can see

Answer (score 1):

To search for a string in the value portion of a dictionary item in python, just loop through all the items and insert items with a matching value into a new dictionary as you go:

```
def filterdict(dict, str):
    results = {}
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if str in value:
            results[key] = value
    return results

#do a quick test to make sure the function works
mydict = {'a': 'just a test',
          'b': 'some',
          'c': 'more',
          'd': 'test',
          'e': 'entries',
          'f': 'test me more!'}

print filterdict(mydict, 'test')
```